# Active vol strategy within a portfolio

Tags: options, portfolio-management, option-strategies

Suppose I'd like to have 10 % of my portfolio allocated to "long volatility" by rolling straddles .

Obviously going all in on one trade implies significant risk of losing all the money. Does anyone know how one could structure such a strategy i.e some kind of simple way to keep a decent amount of capital over time, I do count on losing *some* of it since this is suppose to act as a hedge. Or does anyone know a way one could think about how to structure the buys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google [kelly criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion).

Note whilst some like Buffet follow it in full, some others just take half the sizing to reduce the risks..

Comment: thanks ill read about it ! infinity is far out tho :P

Comment: You know of any other similar strategies for the same problem? That have the same level of simple formulation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertemporal_portfolio_choice has a few utility functions you can check too